# How do I find a list of all objects/variables under an object like $address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

Tags: magento-1.9, quote

```
$address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
```

what else is available from the getQuote() function?
can't find a list anywhere

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different variables you can use. Many start out here: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php

```
string getCreatedAt()
string getUpdatedAt()
string getConvertedAt()
int getIsActive()
int getIsMultiShipping()
int getItemsCount()
float getItemsQty()
int getOrigOrderId()
float getStoreToBaseRate()
float getStoreToQuoteRate()
string getBaseCurrencyCode()
string getStoreCurrencyCode()
string getQuoteCurrencyCode()
float getGrandTotal()
float getBaseGrandTotal()
int getCustomerId()
string getCustomerEmail()
string getCustomerPrefix()
string getCustomerFirstname()
string getCustomerMiddlename()
string getCustomerLastname()
string getCustomerSuffix()
string getCustomerDob()
string getCustomerNote()
int getCustomerNoteNotify()
int getCustomerIsGuest()
string getRemoteIp()
string getAppliedRuleIds()
string getReservedOrderId()
string getPasswordHash()
string getCouponCode()
string getGlobalCurrencyCode()
float getBaseToGlobalRate()
float getBaseToQuoteRate()
string getCustomerTaxvat()
string getCustomerGender()
float getSubtotal()
float getBaseSubtotal()
float getSubtotalWithDiscount()
float getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
int getIsChanged()
int getTriggerRecollect()
string getExtShippingInfo()
int getGiftMessageId()
bool|null getIsPersistent()
```

The above show what you can call in a basic quote. To get like your quote items, you would do something like this:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}
```

For you, when you are editing your code in PHPStorm, I would recommend using a plugin called Magicento. Also, take a look at the database tables and names. A lot of items can be called, however sometimes you'll have to call several items first.

Comment: Thanks for recommending it, the plugin mentioned is here: http://www.magicento.com